# Hyperref and Sideways Figures

Tags: hyperref, rotating

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I don't know much about LaTeX, but I'm trying to reference sideways figures in my text. When I click on the links in the pdf they take me to completely different pages to those intended. All the other links to figures which are not sideways work fine though.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbk}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}                  
\geometry{a4paper,margin=1in,}                 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\newcommand{\LINN}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbk}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pag}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

A map and satellite picture of the study site are presented in figure~\ref{fig:studysite}. 


\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{../../../PHDMaps/Studysite.jpg}
\caption{Map and satellite picture of the study site.\label{fig:studysite}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use the option [demo] for graphicx, wehen the image is not available for others. I cannot see a problem here. Clicking on the link I get the image.

Comment: The center environment is superfluous since the floating environment inside it will "float" out of it.

Comment: Using the `caption` package with `hypcap=true` instead of the `hypcap` package solved this problem for me. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141931/clickable-hyperlinks-wrong-for-sidewaysfigure#141944)

Answer (score 3):

Your example code works fine here. What versions of the hyperref and hypcap package are you using? Please place a `\listfiles` at the head of your document and take a look at the resulting logfiles.

These are the versions I have used:

```
hyperref.sty    2010/10/30 v6.81t Hypertext links for LaTeX
  hypcap.sty    2008/09/08 v1.10 Adjusting anchors of captions (HO)
```

Comment: hyperref 2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX and hypcap 2008/09/08 v1.10 Adjusting anchors of captions (HO). Is there an easy way to update the versions? Thank you very much.

Comment: What LaTeX distribution (i.e. MikTeX, TeX Live, MacTeX) do you have?  Edit: For MikTeX on Windows, use the Update manager, that you'll find in the MikTeX folder in the start menu.