# Clickable hyperlinks wrong for sidewaysfigure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, rotating

I have a few figures which must be shown rotated in landscape orientation. For that I use `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` instead of `\begin{figure}`. But now I found in my text there is a problem between the interaction of `sidewaysfigure` and `hyperref`. While figure numbering is correct both in the caption and the main text, clicking on the cross reference in the text is associated with wrong figures (a few numbers back).

**EDIT:** The following reproduces the problem for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}   % corrects the hyper-anchor of figures/tables

\begin{document}

First: Fig.~\ref{fig:first}. Second: Fig.~\ref{fig:second}.
Third: Fig.~\ref{fig:third}. Fourth: Fig.~\ref{fig:fourth}.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}
\caption{First}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}
\caption{Second}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}
\caption{Third}\label{fig:third}
\end{figure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/zelle148_IMG_1903m.jpg}
\caption{Foruth}\label{fig:fourth}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `hypcap` package, the problem disappears. This is odd as the comment precisely reads "*corrects* the hyper-anchor of figures/tables"...

---

I have found [a very similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7843/hyperref-and-sideways-figures) which is not really answered. Some info from the console when rendering:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
>
> LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>

When I add `\listfiles` as suggested in the other post, I get the following entries:

```
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
hyperref.sty    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
  hypcap.sty    2011/02/16 v1.11 Adjusting anchors of captions (HO)
```

Comment: Can you please give us a compilable code to play with?  If you use package `caption` use option `hypcap=true` instead of package `hypcap`. See documentation of `caption`. Have you considered to update your TeX distribution? Current is TeX Live 2013, you have 2011 ...

Answer (score 4):

Package `hypcap` is a little bit outdated.

In the documentation of package `caption` you can find the description of the new option `hypcap=true` or `hypcap` to get the functionality of old package `hypcap`.

Because you are using package `caption` do not use package `hypcap`.  Please see the documentation of package `caption` for more informations.

Edit:

Your given MWE will work with the small changes I made (I used package `MWE` for the example images, added option `hypcap` and commented package `hypcap`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}  % <==============
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}   % corrects the hyper-anchor of figures/tables % <==============

\begin{document}

First: Fig.~\ref{fig:first}. Second: Fig.~\ref{fig:second}.
Third: Fig.~\ref{fig:third}. Fourth: Fig.~\ref{fig:fourth}.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg} % <==============
\caption{First}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg} % <==============
\caption{Second}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg} % <==============
\caption{Third}\label{fig:third}
\end{figure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg} % <==============
\caption{Foruth}\label{fig:fourth}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed also to update the question to have a reproducible example.